# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor de un mes de una forma más dinámica?

Tags: c#

Quiero obtener el valor del mes como un entero, pero quiero hacerlo de una forma más dinámica para no estar repitiendo cada uno ya que necesito este valor para concatenarlo con otro tipo string y enviarlo a la base de datos

La forma que lo hago ahora es así para poder obtener el valor que requiero para implementarlo en el controlador del sistema

```
 string valor = string.Empty;

 public string MesContrato(string mes)
    {
        if (mes == "enero")
        {
            return valor = "01";
        }
        else if(mes == "febrero")
        {
            return valor = "02";
        }
        else if(mes == "marzo")
        {
            return valor ="03";
        }
        else if (mes == "abril")
        {
            return valor = "04";
        }
        else if (mes == "mayo")
        {
            return valor = "05";
        }
        else if (mes == "junio")
        {
            return valor = "06";
        }
        else if(mes == "julio")
        {
            return valor = "07";
        }
        else if(mes == "agosto")
        {
            return valor = "08";
        }
        else if(mes == "septiembre")
        {
            return valor = "09";
        }
        else if(mes == "octubre")
        {
            return valor = "10";
        }
        else if (mes == "noviembre")
        {
            return valor = "11";
        }
        else if (mes == "diciembre")
        {
            return valor = "12";
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Puedes, o bien usar un array y acceder al indice, o usar un diccionario...hay varias opciones. O si el mes te viene de una fecha, parsearlo a `DateTime` y acceder a la propiedad `Month`.

Comment: Igual ya lo solucionaste.. o sea.. cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo seria:

```
return DateTime.ParseExact(mes, "MMMM", new CultureInfo("es-Es")).Month;
```

Lo pones dentro de un `try catch` y devuelves `null` con la excepción y tienes la misma función.

De todas formas no deberías trabajar nunca con `string` para fechas, deberías usar un objeto `DateTime` o un `int` si es solo el mes.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es no tener tantos If en tu código, te doy esta opción, cargar los meses en una lista de string y luego recorrer la lista comparando si el mes que se escribió es igual a alguno de la lista. Solicito el mes para que el usuario lo escriba, pero igual lo puedes pasar como parámetro y cuando lo compares, trata de poner el parámetro como ToUpper, para que sin importar lo que el usuario escriba o mande, siempre sea mayúscula, esto porque si tienes en tu lista "Enero" y alguien digita enero o ENERO, te dirá que no es un mes correcto, sin embargo es porque la cadena no tiene la similutd entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Espero te ayude:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Escriba el parámetro del Mes");
        string Parametro = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

        List<string> Meses = new List<string> { "ENERO-01", "FEBRERO-02","MARZO-03","ABRIL-04","MAYO-05" };
        
        string MesContrato = "";

        foreach (var Mes in Meses)
        {
            string[] MesNombre = Mes.Split('-');

            if (MesNombre[0] == Parametro.ToUpper())
            {
                MesContrato = MesNombre[1];
                break;
            }
            else {
                MesContrato = null;
            }
        }

        if (MesContrato != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El numero de Mes es " + MesContrato);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Favor escribir un mes correcto");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
```